# Automatically click the button when opening the page through the controller

Tags: laravel

I have a modal window on my page that contains a form.When a user submits an invalid form, he gets a list of errors.These errors are reported through the controller.When submitting, the page is updated and the modal window needs to be opened again on the button. Is it possible to somehow automatically press the button when opening the page through the controller?

Controller

```
public function CreateUser(UserPostRequest $req, $id){
        $validated = $req->validated();
        $user = new User();
        ...
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('org-data-by-id',  $id);
    }
```

View

```
 <button id="btnOpenModal" class="btn btn-success">Add User</button>
 <div id="myModal" class="mymodal">
        @if($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $message)
                        <li> {{$message}}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

      <form style="margin: 20px;" action="/org/{{$data->id}}/adduser" method="post">
        @csrf
       ...

        <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id="btnCloseModal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You must use ajax/axios submit form. When you use ajax it will be easy and right way. Or not use modals for form

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your page open the modal, you can put something like this in your page:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('btnOpenModal').click();
</script>
```

But you probably don't want it displayed every time the page is opened. If you only want to show it when there are errors, you could do this:

```
@if($errors->any())
  <script>
    document.getElementById('btnOpenModal').click();
  </script>
@endif
```